# Should ‘Were’ be used with any impossible situation even without wish?

Tags: grammar, verbs, wish

My question comes from the sentence below:

```
I wish there were something to help you with.
```

Supposing that I want to say the exact same thing but with `thought`. Should I say:

```
I thought there were something I could help you with.
```

Or

```
I thought there was something I could help you with.
```

Can the first one be true when I’m sure that there is nothing I can help that person with or the `were` structure is dedicated to `wish`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In modern English, that use (which is the sole surviving instance of the old subjunctive form of the verb) is used only with *wish* and with conditionals (*if*, *whether*, literary inversion).

Older English allowed it with a wider range of verbs, but it has survived  only in those two contexts (and not at all for some English speakers).

Comment: Is this a dialect thing? I say "I wish there was", "if only there was", ...

Comment: Yes, but it's not a geographic or regional dialect so much as a social one. (Which means that people who do use _were_ are often under the misapprehension that their dialect is "correct" and other people's is "wrong").

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for your answer. So, for stuff that you mentioned above, `were` and `was` can both be correct but in most exams, I see `were` as the correct form but I regularly hear natives use `was` that might be because of the changes that the speech grammar receives in most languages; Is my thought right? But the one with `thought` is wrong based on your answer. If any of my stuff are wrong, please let me know and thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

Both should be "was."

"Something" is singular.

Example:

I wish there were people I could talk to about this.
I wish there was a person I could talk to about this.

Comment: Hi. Well, the structures suggest that `were` should be used with impossible things. Like, `I wish I were taller`. Is it not right? https://www.quora.com/Is-it-correct-to-say-I-wish-she-were-here

Comment: Well, I think @ColinFine does explain this perfectly .

Comment: No. For people who use _irrealis_ "were" (such as me), @NUMERICALUDD 's first sentence is fine. Furthermore, people who believe that _irrealis_ "were" is "correct" (not including me), would judge your version of the first with "was" as "incorrect". This has nothing to do with number. (To clarify: I don't believe in "correct" and "incorrect". I prefer standard and non-standard). -1

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for your time for writing all of this and also, sorry for being late. I appreciate it. 